# Staff with more than Average Salary but less then that of a Manager? (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello I am at a loss what to do here being quite the beginner at SQL , I have already calcalated how to show all people that have a Salary which is more than average.

I now need to show all people with a Salary greater than the Average but less than that of the Supervisor.

Here is the Code I entered to get the Salary greater than Average.

```
select first_name, last_name, salary
from staff
where salary >(select avg(salary) from staff);
```

This is the first section done but I don't know how to calcalate Salarys for if: People have a salary less then that of a supervisor but more than the Average.

The Tables contains:

First_Name, Last_Name, Role, Salary

Comment: You say `the supervisor` ... is there only one?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to clarify this. Yes there is only one in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a second condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
select first_name, last_name, salary
from staff
where salary > (select avg(salary) from staff) and
      salary < (select min(salary) from staff where role = 'supervisor')
```

I am interpreting the logic to be that you want to add a condition that the salary be less than *any* supervisor.  In case there be only one supervisor, the above query should still be correct.

Comment: Thank you very much , This result worked perfectly I will make sure to remeber this for my future use.